# ListView in android from 2 dynamic strings arrays

Tags: android, string, listview, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListView in android from 2 dynamic strings arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558337/listview-in-android-from-2-dynamic-strings-arrays)

I have two string arrays, here s1[] contains a list of names and s2[] contains URL's associated with the respective name, now i need to populate ListView, with the names and on clicking any of the names, i want to start an intent for the browser to handle the URL.

How do i do that, I am extremely confused about ListViews in general.

Answer (score 1):

Watch the video from this Google I/O talk last year. It gives an introduction to ListView, when it's appropriate to use, and associated best practices. http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html