# ListView in android from 2 dynamic strings arrays

Tags: android, string, dynamic

I have two string arrays, here s1[] contains a list of names and s2[] contains URL's associated with the respective name, now i need to populate ListView, with the names and on clicking any of the names, i want to start an intent for the browser to handle the URL.

How do i do that?

Comment: Also, you posted this question twice in the past hour.  That's not how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array adapter to populate the listview from s1, and in the click handler for the listview find the URL for the given list position, and fire off an intent to the browser.

For an example of using an array adapter see the [API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) and in particular [list1](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List1.html).

For an example of setting an activity as an onItemClickListener see https://github.com/nikclayton/android-squeezer/blob/cache-server-data/src/com/danga/squeezer/AlbumsListActivity.java#L88 and https://github.com/nikclayton/android-squeezer/blob/cache-server-data/src/com/danga/squeezer/AlbumsListActivity.java#L288.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like:

```
class Link{
    public String name;
    public String link;
}
```

You can then  create a custom listview which extends 'ArrayAdapter' and override 'getView' as well as 'onItemSelected'.  In both of these method you will be able to get the item using the 'position' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity{

private ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    urls.add("http://www.google.com");
    names.add("google");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, names);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    String url = urls.get(position);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}